# ASP.Net xml session string to data control

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, session, linq-to-xml

I've been doing a web configurator for some time now, and finally it's getting finished. Here is where I got stuck. I save some data into an xml from the code-behind (C#), using Linq.  Fine, I use `XDocument` to create the xml, and then I can save that xml to a Session variable.

Now, my problem is that I want to show that xml data organized to the user.  So, how can I show that xml data(which get stored in a session variable as a string)?  Should I parse the string and assign it to a control?  I think showing the xml data through a control would be the correct thing to do, but that data comes from a string session.  Example of what I have in mind:

```
Control.DataSource = Session["theXmlDocument"].ToString()?;Control.DataBind();
```

or

```
Control.DataSource = XDocument. _
```

This last line would be the creation of the XML at the same time of asigning it to the control.  Any ideas??? I just want to show a control with xml data, where the data source may be from a session with a string, or something similar like that.  I know XMLDataSource exists, but not like I want it to work.  Is it possible?

Comment: Then why don't just show the string (you are right about not needing to create xdocument in this case as it is a waste of resources)

Comment: Because if I just show the string, it won't be formatted to the user.

Comment: True about the waste of resources, so that's why I use a session.  Also I need to to save that data I want to show into XML for later use.

Comment: Ok, in that case, you want it formatted - do use XDocument.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the xml to the user, why not just use a `<textarea>` element?

In your Controller, just have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    YourModel m = new YourModel ();
    m.xml = Session["theXmlDocument"] as XDocument;
    return View(m);
}
```

Then in your view, display the xml from your model in a `<textarea>`:

```
<textarea style="width: 600px; height: 400px">
     @Model.xml.ToString() 
</textarea>
```

XDocument.ToString() indents the xml string by default, and here is an example of the result in IE:
[image]